# ssrs matrix on both pages of same page, blank page appears

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a ssrs report to build. I need print out both sides. One side is a matrix. It's like 2x2 table. load details information of every customer. The other side is Customer contact information, also like 2x2 table . So after print it, we can cut it to 4 piece. Now I set report page size 8.5x11 with margin (.5,.5,.5,.5) on position(0,0) body size 16x10. I put second matrix on position (8.5,0). 
Now I there is blank page after front side. It's like Front side, blank page, back side, Front side, blank page, back side...
How to get rid of the blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move the second matrix next to first one. Now problem is solved.